# Identifying the particular CRUD operation from the session object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am relatively new to hibernate. I am developing a java application which uses hibernate to do the basic CRUD operations. I wanted to add some logic specifically when I am doing a read from database. For all the operations, I do a `session.createQuery` to generate the query and do the operation. Is there some flag available in session object or any other related objects which differentiates a read/find operation from the rest of the CRUD operations. I wanted to add the logic where I create the HQL query from the session object.

Thanks in advance for any help in this regard.

Comment: I'm confused.  Don't you already know what operation you're about to perform just from where you are in the program?  It doesn't really make sense for the session to track that, since the same session could be used for many different operations, even within a unit of work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use criteria, for example to find all objects related to the class USER:

```
public List<USER> findAllOBJECTS() {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("nom"));;
        return (List<USER>) criteria.list();
    }
```

or if you want to search for a user by his login for example:

```
public USER findByLOGIN(String login) {
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("login", login));
        USER user = (USER)crit.uniqueResult();           
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question.  The Asker seems to know how to create a query already using `createQuery`